# What is the difference between Rich Push and Push at urbanrairship.

Tags: iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am using push notification via urbanairship.com. 
Urbanairship also provides rich push notifications. I am implementing a group chat based system, I want to know if I can use a rich push notification service instead of normal push notifications on  urbanairship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our product listing for Rich Push is here: http://urbanairship.com/products/rich-push/

You can see here: http://urbanairship.com/docs/richpush.html#sending-messages that all items except "message" are optional. Message == rich push body.

I'm not sure I understand the question 100%, however, if you are looking to use rich push instead of push notifications that is certainly possible. You can send a Rich Push notification to an app without a corresponding push notification.

Does that answer your question?

Anthony